# Android: Reading a self-modifying NFC tag continuously (NXP NT3H2211)

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef

I'm currently working on a project, trying out NXP's NT3H2211 IC which is an NFC tag, containing a 64 Byte SRAM, which can be mapped into the address space visible from the NFC interface. The IC is contained within this development kit: NTAG I²C plus Explorer Kit (http://www.nxp.com/demoboard/OM5569).

This SRAM can be used to enable dynamically changing data being read/written with any standard NFC reader, without wearing out the EEPROM area in a few hours (eg reading sensor data or streaming data for processing; reading live data from a machine as a contactless debugging interface, etc.).

I'm still very new to Android programming (in Android Studio), and with the help of a tutorial video series, I have managed to build an App which reads the tag a single time, once the phone is tapped to it. To my understanding, the app does this by waiting for an intent which contains some kind of information that an NFC tag has been found.

I'm continuously updating the Tag's SRAM with a valid, auto-generated NDEF plaintext message (at the moment, just containing the uptime of my board in seconds), so therefore I'd like to be able to read the tag continuously as well.

The supplied demo app from NXP (NTAG I²C DEMO) can do this; there's a section for reading NDEF records. The NDEF reader can be set to read continuously, by checking the "Enable NDEF read loop" check box. With this, I can see my data updating. 
The app also does not rely on having to remove the phone and re-tapping it to the tag to perform actions - once the tag is on the phone's reader, every feature can be used without re-tapping.

I'd like to incorporate a feature-set like this in my own app as well; having to re-tap every time I want to update my on-screen data can be very frustrating after a while.

I'm not entirely sure on how to re-use the intent that was originally used to detect and then read the tag; maybe that's the key.

If you need the code, just say so. I really appreciate you taking your time and helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

The source code of the demo app is available at http://www.nxp.com/documents/software/SW3648.zip.

You should be able to read continuously after the event, by setting an appropriate flag.

Comment: Link is not accessible.